# Phpmyadmin session timeout on Plesk

Tags: php

How can I increase the amount of time a phpmyadmin session is valid when running through Plesk?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

There is a value you can set in the phpmyadmin config, but I've been told in some cases, a php.ini config overrides it. So, one configuration you can try is opening up */etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php*. At the end of the file, put:

```
$cfg['LoginCookieValidity'] = xx;
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', $cfg['LoginCookieValidity']);
```

Replace *xx* with the amount of seconds you want the session to be valid for. Also, that is the correct phpmyadmin config file to modify when using Plesk (9.2.3).

Comment: I can confirm that this solution does not work